# Import XML preserve attribute order

Tags: xml, microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I am trying to integrate a web app with a Microsoft Navision. I have setup the xmlport and have successfully exported the relevant XML. The problem begins when I try to import the XML back to NAV, because I process the data and re-write the XML, I cannot force the order of the attributes and I get the following error message

> The attribute is required and don't match...

Can you please help me?

Comment: You should add more details to your question, maybe parts of XML and/or you code. At the moment it's unlikely that anyone can help with your problem.

Comment: The attributes doesn't have to be in the same order - something else is wrong in this case I think. If you can post the XMLport and the XML file, I'm sure we can help

Answer (score 1):

[**Attribute order is insignificant**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) per the [**XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant.

**Therefore, no compliant XML application will expect attributes to be in any particular order.**

You're either dealing with an unusual and non-compliant XML application, or (more likely), you're misinterpreting the (incomplete?) error message that you've posted.